# Solving a system of trigonometric equations. with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Is numerical solving of the problem in the picture below even possible? 
[image: Picture of the eq syste]

Edit: The code does not output anything, it just runs for 20min+

```
(eqs[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] = 
{0 == G lk Cos[p1] + 7/2 mk g lk Cos[p1] - k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p1], 
0 == G lk Cos[p2] + 5/2 mk g lk Cos[p2] - kt p2 - kt (p2 + p3) - k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p2], 
0 == -3/2 mk g lk Cos[p3] - kt p3 - kt (p2 + p3) - k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p3], 
0 == -1/2 mk g lk Cos[p4] - k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p4]}) // 
TableForm
```

Edit 2: 
Thank you for trying to help me. So after looking at my assignment again, i am not sure that posted equations are okay.  So I tried to simplify it. My code now is:

```
mk = 240; (*kg*)
G = 41200;(*N*)
Iu = 15*10^-7; (*m4*)
lk = 69/100;(*m*)
Eu = 210*10^9; (*Pa = N/m^2*)
k = 1*10^7 ;(*N/m*)
g = 981*10^-2;(*m/s^2*)
EI = Eu Iu;
P = 4;
kt = (EI/lk)(*Nm/rad*)
```

Equations:

```
Q1[\[Phi]1_, \[Phi]2_, \[Phi]3_, \[Phi]4_] = 
  G lk Cos[\[Phi]1]  + 7/2 mk g lk Cos[\[Phi]1] - kt \[Phi]1 + 
   kt \[Phi]2;
Q2[\[Phi]1_, \[Phi]2_, \[Phi]3_, \[Phi]4_] = 
  G lk Cos[\[Phi]2] + 5/2 mk g lk Cos[\[Phi]2] + kt \[Phi]1 - 
   2 kt \[Phi]2 - kt \[Phi]3;
Q3 [\[Phi]1_, \[Phi]2_, \[Phi]3_, \[Phi]4_] = - (3/2)
      mk g lk Cos[\[Phi]3] - kt \[Phi]2 - 2 kt \[Phi]3 + kt \[Phi]4;
Q4[\[Phi]1_, \[Phi]2_, \[Phi]3_, \[Phi]4_] =  - (1/2)
      mk g lk Cos[\[Phi]4] - kt \[Phi]4 + kt \[Phi]3;
```

And my only half successful attempt:

```
r = FindRoot[{
   Q1[\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4] ,
   Q2 [\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4],
   Q3 [\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4],
   Q4[\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4]}, {{\[Phi]1, 
    0.001}, {\[Phi]2, 0.001}, {\[Phi]3, 0.001}, {\[Phi]4, 0.001}}]
```

The result that i get is not what i was expecting (3/2pi, 3/2pi, -3/2pi, -3/2pi).
Any hints ? 
I tried also NSolve, Solve, Find.....

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post code, not images.

Comment: `G=1;lk=2;mk=3;g=4;kt=5;k=6;FindRoot[{q1==0,q2==0,q3==0,q4==0},{{p1,1},{p2,1},{p3,1},{p4,1}}]` instantly returns a solution for your system. Substitute your actual values for your parameters and see if it works. Substitute better starting values for p1,p2,p3,p4 if you are looking for a solution near some known point.

Comment: -1. The code still is not presented.

Comment: Closing this until the OP provides copyable code.

Comment: @J. M.'s technical difficulties, in my answer there is copyable code.

Comment: Whatever is wanted remains underspecified.

Comment: The `Edit2 ` system can be solved easily.  `{\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4}/Pi /. 
 Solve[-2 Pi < \[Phi]4 < 2 Pi && 
   And @@ Thread[eqs == 0], {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2, \[Phi]3, \[Phi]4}, 
  Reals] ` yields  `{{-(3/2), -(3/2), 3/2, 3/2}, {-(1/2), -(1/2), 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/
  2, -(1/2), -(1/2)}, {3/2, 3/2, -(3/2), -(3/2)}} ` . Test it with FindRoot.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be impossible to solve with NSolve. Even elimination of Sin[pi] or Cos[pi] didn't improve it.

With different starting points for FindRoot, it can be observed, that p1 and p4 alyways end in multiples of Pi/2. I can't proove this generally, but it seems plausible, since p1 and p4 only appear in  sin and cos in equations. Maybe some clever guy can show it.

Inserting only multiples of Pi/2 for p1 and p4, you can find all solutions for p2, p3 graphically as starting points for FindRoot.

```
(eqs[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] = 
{0 == G lk Cos[p1] + 7/2 mk g lk Cos[p1] - 
  k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p1], 
0 == G lk Cos[p2] + 5/2 mk g lk Cos[p2] - kt p2 - kt (p2 + p3) - 
  k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p2], 
0 == -3/2 mk g lk Cos[p3] - kt p3 - kt (p2 + p3) - 
  k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[p3], 
0 == -1/2 mk g lk Cos[p4] - 
  k 4 lk (Sin[p1] + Sin[p2] - Sin[p3] - Sin[p4]) Cos[
    p4]}) // TableForm

FindRoot[eqs[p1, p2, p3, p4] /. {G -> 1, lk -> 2, mk -> 3, g -> 4, 
    kt -> 5, k -> 6}, {{p1, 1}, {p2, 1}, {p3, 1}, {p4, 1}}]

(*   {p1 -> 1.5708, p2 -> 1.13895, p3 -> 2.28885, p4 -> 1.5708}   *)

{p1, p2, p3, p4}/Pi /. 
   FindRoot[eqs[p1, p2, p3, p4] /. {G -> 1, lk -> 2, mk -> 3, g -> 4, 
kt -> 5, k -> 6}, {{p1, 2}, {p2, 4}, {p3, 1}, {p4, 0}}]

(*    {0.5, 1.6984, -1.66635, 1.5}   multiples of Pi   *)

{p1, p2, p3, p4}/Pi /. 
   FindRoot[eqs[p1, p2, p3, p4] /. {G -> 1, lk -> 2, mk -> 3, g -> 4, 
kt -> 5, k -> 6}, {{p1, 7}, {p2, 1}, {p3, 1}, {p4, 5}}]

(*   {2.5, 0.0223505, 0.565737, 1.5}   *)
```

Evaluate for given parameters and multiples of Pi/2. If equation yields True, it is valid for all pi. In this case no graph appears.

Solutions for p2,p3 are where all appearing graphes intersect.

**Edit**

Now taking into account, that overdetermined equations do not give a solution. there remain only 4 combinations.

```
soleqs = Select[
  Flatten[Table[{{p1, p4}, 
 DeleteCases[
  Evaluate[
   eqs[p1, p2, p3, p4] /. {G -> 1, lk -> 2, mk -> 3, g -> 4, 
     kt -> 5, k -> 6}], True]}, {p1, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}, {p4, 0, 2 Pi,
  Pi/2}], 1], Length[#[[2]]] == 2 &]

ContourPlot[Evaluate[#[[2]]], {p2, 0, 2 Pi}, {p3, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Magenta}, 
  PlotLabel -> {{"p1=", #[[1, 1]]}, {"p4=", #[[1, 2]]}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 150] & /@ soleqs
```

[image]